# Exchange 2010 double sending automatic replies

Tags: exchange-2010

A bit of an odd situation has come up. My exchange 2010 server has started to send double "Automatic Reply" messages recently and I'm not quite sure why this is happening.

The only change that we've made recently was we had an Exchange Server that we were replicating to with Double Take availability, and we stopped the job on the weekend to send the machine offsite to our DR site. It was around this time that the double-messages started to send both internally and externally. It is happening with all of our accounts and to internal as well as external accounts. All Automatic Replies have been set with the assistant in either OWA or Outlook 2010

Has anyone encountered this before and if so do you know how to resolve it?

Comment: OOF replies or automatic replies using rules?

Comment: Automatic Replies w/ the assistant - formerly known as an OOF reply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to resolve this issue by installing SP2 Rollup 5v2